# Is "There was a group of people who were enjoying it" grammatically correct?

Tags: grammaticality, grammatical-number, verb-agreement, relative-clauses, collective-nouns

I heard this on TV (in reference to a Trump rally), but although it "sounds" all right, it doesn't seem to be grammatically correct since "group" is the subject.

> There was a group of people who were enjoying it.

Wouldn't the correct way instead be as follows?

> There was a group of people who was enjoying it.

It seems technically better, but to my ears the double usage of "was" almost makes it sound worse.

Comment: It was a singular group. The group was made *of* (multiple) "people who were ...".

Comment: Notional agreement for collective nouns has been done to death on ELU. Here, I'd rephrase on style grounds to 'There was a group of people; they were enjoying it.' or, if restrictive, 'There was _one_ group of people who were enjoying it.'

Comment: It was the people who were enjoying it, not the group. The group is the aggregate of the "people who were enjoying". So it's actually the singular "was enjoying" that sounds a bit strange, because a group can't enjoy anything. Unless it's being used as a stand-in for "group of people," as in "the Republican group was enjoying it."

Answer (score 2):

If you want *enjoying* to apply to the group as a whole, you have to use *that* rather than *who*.

> There was a group of people that was enjoying it.

When you use *who*, it refers to *people*, which is plural, so it needs a plural verb. Switching to *that* changes the reference to *group*, which is singular.

You can also say:

> There was a group of people that were enjoying it.

There is a very subtle difference, I believe. The first emphasizes that the group as a whole is enjoying it. The second emphasizes that a number of people are enjoying it, and then defines the group in terms of those people.

Comment: _Were_ could also be used with _that_, since it can also refer to _people_ in this sentence.

Comment: @JohnLawler Take a look at the addition I made regarding that variation. Do you agree with my assessment?

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I get stuck into such a situation, I think of my mother tongue (Urdu_Pakistan). It gives me two senses, both of them seem true and do not sound ambiguous to me. I think whether it is 'was' or 'were', it depends upon you what you want to get out of it.

Comment: The question is about English usage. How or why does Urdu help explain English usage?

Answer (score 0):

..............There...............was... {a group of people who were enjoying it.}

Adverb(complement)... verb......................... subject

Thus we have

There was a group {of [people who were enjoying it]}.

[people who were enjoying it] is a noun phrase made up of a noun (people) + relative clause (who were enjoying it).

{of [people who were enjoying it]} is a prepositional adjectival clause modifying "group"

Thus because the referent of "who" is "people", "were" is correct.